# Where to release a view controller in a Block

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Hi I using blocks to implement the pushing of viewcontrollers onto a stack. My code is as follows:

My Question is, for memory management, where can I release the firstView instance? I tried to release it in the completion block itself but I will get a "memory issue" if I press the back button from splashView to the firstView

```
FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

[firstView setCompletionHandler:^(BOOL isRequestInvite){

    splashView=[[AuthSplashController alloc] init];
    [splashView setCompletionHandler:onceCompleted];

    [navCon pushViewController:splashView animated:YES];
    //[firstView release];

}];

[navCon pushViewController:firstView animated:NO];
```

So in this case, where would be the best place to release firstView?

Comment: Correct answer: throw on ARC and don't release anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can `release` `firstView` after pushing it on navigation stack, because retain count will be increased:

```
 [navCon pushViewController:firstView animated:NO];
 [firstView release];
```

Or you can mark that object as `autoreleased`:

```
 FirstViewController *firstView = [[[FirstViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Comment: +1 as soon as controller is pushed the navcon takes ownership. autorelease form is less confusing

Comment: What's the best practice?  When and why should you autorelease vs. release specifically in code?  I have always explicitly done a release at the end of the code block allocating/pushing the view.

Comment: In my opinion, `release` is better.